# adding groups in Davical lead to errors

Tags: php, postgresql

Hi I'm trying to install Davical next to Nextcloud with Postgres, nginx and php8.1, it works partially already (Adding users or resources works fine), but when I want to create groups I get the following error messages:

I can create groups in the admin panel, but when I call up the group page (`https://calendar.example.de/admin.php?action=edit&t=principal&id=1019`)
I get this error message under "Group membership":

```
Exception [42601] SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 FEHLER:  Müll folgt auf numerische Konstante bei »1019O«
ZEILE 1: ...member WHERE group_id = 1019) AND principal_id != 1019ORDER ...
                                                              ^
At line 95 of /usr/share/awl/inc/AwlDatabase.php
================= Stack Trace ===================
/usr/share/davical/htdocs/admin.php[50] Browser->Render()
/usr/share/awl/inc/classBrowser.php[852] edit_group_row()
/usr/share/davical/inc/ui/principal-edit.php[591] Editor->Render()
/usr/share/awl/inc/classEditor.php[669] preg_replace_callback()
[0] Editor->ReplaceEditorPart()
/usr/share/awl/inc/classEditor.php[597] EntryField::BuildOptionList()
/usr/share/awl/inc/DataEntry.php[306] AwlQuery->Exec()
/usr/share/awl/inc/AwlQuery.php[585] AwlQuery->Execute()
/usr/share/awl/inc/AwlQuery.php[396] AwlDatabase->query()
/usr/share/awl/inc/AwlDatabase.php[95] PDO->query()
```

and I am unable to add users to groups.

there are also the following error messages in the Davical error log

```
2023/04/26 11:38:59 [error] 330989#330989: *17 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Early Exception: [42601] SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 FEHLER:  Müll folgt auf numerische Konstante bei »1019O«
ZEILE 1: ...member WHERE group_id = 1019) AND principal_id != 1019ORDER ...
 ^ at /usr/share/awl/inc/AwlDatabase.php:95" while reading upstream, client: 192.168.100.2, server: calendar.example.de, request: "GET /admin.php?action=edit&t=principal&id=1019 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "calendar.example.de"
```

The postgresql error log says:

```
2023-04-26 11:59:29.228 CEST [333501] davical_app@davical ANWEISUNG:  SELECT principal_id, coalesce(displayname,fullname,username) FROM dav_principal WHERE principal_id NOT IN (SELECT member_id FROM group_member WHERE group_id = 1019) AND principal_id != 1019ORDER BY 2
```

using ubuntu 22.04, php8.1, postgresql 15, Davical 1.1.11-1, libawl-php  0.63-1 all

I checked the php8.1-fpm.sock, both in the www.conf and in the corresponding nginx config the link to the socket is correct.
The php8.1.-fpm.sock is available, user rights and owner seem to be set correctly.
Maybe I missed something, or is there an error in the postgresql database?
Can anybody help me further?

Thanks!

Comment: `principal_id != 1019ORDER BY 2` insert space between `1019` and `ORDER`?

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that too, but I think (and hope) that it's not a bug in DaviCal. Is it possible that a bad Nginx config is causing the missing space?

Comment: Looks like a bug in DaviCal, that's where this piece of SQL has been generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code is wrong:

```
  $sql = 'SELECT principal_id, coalesce(displayname,fullname,username) FROM dav_principal ';
  $sql .= 'WHERE principal_id NOT IN (SELECT member_id FROM group_member WHERE group_id = '.$id.') ';
  $sql .= 'AND principal_id != '.$id;
  $sql .= 'ORDER BY 2';
```

The ORDER BY gets stuck right after $id, resulting in the error message you see.

Fix: Extra space right before the ORDER BY:

```
  $sql .= ' ORDER BY 2';
```

The file can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/davical-project/davical/-/blob/master/inc/ui/principal-edit.php), principal-edit.php

Comment: Thanks very much! where exactly is the code?

Comment: It's principal-edit.php, see the link

Comment: By the way, the root cause for this kind of error is the fact that this code generates a string that should represent a piece of SQL. Using a prepared statement would make this code less error prone. There would be no need for string concatenation at all.